mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied with MySQL 8.0 and google sql
Trying to upgrade to mysql 8 from mysql 5.7 on google sql. I'm unable to mysqlimport my csv file as the root user due to permissions. The message is 'mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation'. I'm unable to set any of these permissions as the root user.
mysqlimport my csv file on google mysql 8. Works fine on mysql 5.7

Why don't you simply use load data infile statement to load the csv file?

I would prefer not to have to change my existing scripts which work perfectly within a stock version of mysql 8, as well as within mysql 5.7 on the google platform. My guess is that this issue is due to the way in which google provisions mysql 8, and not due to differences with mysql 5.7 vs 8.
Note also that mysqlimport resolves to 'load data' under the covers. They should work the same out of the box.

Mysqlimport uses load data infile, but probably tries to set mysql variables that you can't change under gcp-hosted mysql. So, using just load data infile could work for you.

Well, using 'load data' does not throw a security error and it does import if the input file contains a small number of rows. Unfortunately, loading a large (56MB) file just hangs (never finishes). Oh well, guess that's for another post. Thank you

56MB is not particularly a big file nowadays. Load data infile can handle files lot bigger than that.

I was able to use 'load data' instead of mysqlimport (which appears to be prohibited on gcp-hosted mysql 8+. It works on mysql 5.7)
